# vlc broke after nvidia-375 update (xenial 16.04); libgles1-mesa vs libgles2-mesa

Tags: nvidia, vlc

**tl;dr**

How do I get vlc working with nvidia-375 and Xenial (16.04)?

**Context**

On April 10 2017, apt, via the x-org-edgers PPA updated my nvidia drivers from nvidia-367 to nvidia-375.

Shortly after vlc stopped working.

I uninstalled and tried to reinstall vlc, but got this:

```
 vlc : Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles1
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Question**

- How do I get VLC working again?
- How should I set up my ppa so that once nvidia/display it does not update it? (i.e. remove the ppa file from /etc/apt/sources.list.d )

*A few points*

- I probably should not have the 'x-org edgers' PPA but i moved my settings from a prior laptop where some display features did not work
- I don't do anything fancy graphics-wise (gaming, etc): just drive a 4K display and want suspend/resume to work correctly
- I've tried reverting to nvidia-367, but that did not seem to fix the problem. (Nor am I sure it installed correctly).

thanks

**Update #1**

I ran ppa purge for xorg-edgers and installed nvidia-current drivers:

```
   $ sudo ppa-purge  ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
   $ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
   $ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

**Update #2**

Here is policy for libgles1-mesa as well as output of install nvidia-current

```
$ sudo  apt-cache policy libgles1-mesa libgles1-mesa:
   Installed: (none)
   Candidate: 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
   Version table:
         12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
            500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
         11.2.0-1ubuntu2 500
            500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64
```

Packages

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-current is already the newest version (304.135-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
```

Update #3: output of "apt-get install vlc"

```
$sudo apt-get install vlc

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: You mention the xorg-edgers a couple of times in your question, and also state you 'probably should not have' it - Why not remove it and perform a general update, reinstall vlc and see if this helps the problem?  `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`

Comment: OK. I Ran ppa-purge ...rebooted...reverted drivers back to 304 "sudo apt-get install nvidia-current"...I stilll get the  "unmet dependencies" with libgles1-messa when I try to install vlc

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy libgles1-mesa`, and can you append the full text of the output of `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` to your question?

Comment: I've added these in "update #2" section of the question above

Comment: Thanks - I'm really sorry, but I meant to type in the full text of the output of `sudo apt-get install vlc`

Comment: I've added output of 'sudo install vlc' in update #3 above

Comment: Thanks - I think that your solution will lie in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa).  It seems that you probably have a PPA or two in your system that are preventing the installation.